# Javascript Function for button doesen't result correctly

Tags: javascript

By clicking button, I would like to have:
- 1 prompt to enter my password - IF correct -> goes to a page, if not:
-2nd prompt -> if correct password -> goes to a page, if not:
-3rd prompt -> if correct password -> goes to page, if not:

```
alert('you failed')
```

Currently it doesen't read the 2nd prompt, nor it makes the final alert.

The code:

```
function passWord() {
var number = 0;
var pass1 = prompt('Give password','your password...... ');
while (number < 3) {




if (pass1=="montpellier") {
        alert('Success.... you're being redirected');
        window.open("quiz.php");

    } else {
        number =+ 1;
        var pass2=prompt('Try again','paassword....');
        if (pass2=="montpellier & number < 3) {
            alert('Success....you'rebeing redirected');
        window.open("quiz.php");
        } else {
            alert('You failed');
            window.history.back();
    }
}
}
```

When I try to enter the password on the second prompt, it just continues to make prompts until number < 3.

Comment: Some of the problem you're having may be due to your string encasing. Since you have an apostrophe in the string, try using quotation marks to encase it instead.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting on this page - it should be clear there is some invalid syntax. `alert('Success....you're being redirected');` Where does this String start and end? Where is it _supposed_ to start and end?

Comment: I actually even tried it with `alert("Success..you'rebeing redirected");` and it still doesen't work correctly.

Comment: This is the edited code which actually works as intended:

`function passWord() {
var number = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Please type the password in order to proceed:','type your password....');

 
 if (pass1=="123") {
  alert('This is correct, you can proceed.');
  window.open('quiz.php');
 } while (number < 3 & pass1 != "123") {
    number = number + 1;
    pass1 = prompt("Wrong ! Try again !");
  if (pass1=="123") {
 alert("You're good to go!");
  window.open("quiz.php");
    } else if (number==3) {
     alert('Try again');
     window.history.back();
    }
 }
}`